# Can we use meta for gaming related discussions?

Tags: discussion, meta

I like this community and I want a community like this to have 'philosophical' discussions with (such as the nature of IP rights and so on)

Is it possible to use meta for stuff like "What is your opinion of blah blah's game/software ownership philosophy"?

I understand that this is not the intention of the meta, but occasionally a question on the parent raises an interesting question that would be nice to discuss without the restrictions of objectivity.

Comment: Give it a try and see if @Robert or @Jeff allows it ;-)

Comment: Oh and come up with your own version of the dreaded [always-friday-in-iceland]

Comment: @ivo `[uuddlrlrabab]`

Comment: @Mechko: Accept @Oak's answer (or any of the same sentiment). That's the only answer. Meta *has to* stay focused on meta (i.e. stuff *about* the site). Too much noise and the purpose of meta  gets drowned out.

Comment: A good fourth place would be a message board where we could migrate discussions to.

Comment: @ivo `[the-cake-is-a-lie]`, `[insert-coin]`, `[wakka-wakka-wakka]`, `[excuuuuuuuuse-me-princess]`, `[do-a-barrel-roll]`, `[kekekeke]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think these sort of questions are quite interesting. I think they absolutely do **not** belong here in meta, in any way or form. In my opinion, *this place should remain solely dedicated for discussing the parent site.*

Comment: Isn't part of meta's mandate to be the after hours bar to the main site?  In that context, such discussion is appropriate.

Comment: @tzenes: it is? The "What kind of questions can I ask here?" and "What kind of questions should I not ask here?" in the meta's FAQ are *very* clear regarding this. I suppose everything can be changed, I'm just not aware of such discussions being part of the mandate right now.

Comment: Would it be a breach of etiquette to offer a space for said conversations and ask it to be pointed to in the case that said questions rise?

Comment: I agree, meta.so is not used for discussion on programming for example. Until we have the third place (i'm hoping it will be very soon), there's no home for this kind of things no matter how interesting they are

Comment: @Juan well SO is for programming, but not meta programming, would meta.SO be for meta programming or meta programming questions.

Comment: no, meta.so is for "discussion" about the engine. This meta would be for discussion about this site, what is allowed, what tags to use, etc @tze

Comment: @Juan so meta SE questions, not meta SE (despite the name).

Answer (score 1):

This is what the '[third place](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/)' will be for.

Comment: the problem is that the third place is supposed to be a chat system which makes it great for immediate conversations, but not so good for posteriority or opening up to interested people who aren't there at the right time.  In anycase, we'll see what happens.

Comment: The chat is intended for elaboration of complex answers and clarification on questions, although new rooms could be abused... A [Fourth Place](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling) might be useful or not, the votes indicate no...

Answer (score -1):

Ask them on the main site, when the close police will delete your question mercilessly, or discuss them in the third place. :/