# Dwarf Fortress Succession

Tags: discussion, dwarf-fortress

Would organizing a DF succession game on meta be off-topic?

Answer (score 5):

I don't quite know what a succession game is, but this sounds along the lines of any manner of scheduling for net-gaming matches or organizing collaborative play.

In which the answer is **it is off-topic**. Related: [Oak's answer here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/712/is-oak-actually-a-pokemon-professor-in-disguise/713#713).

The site Meta is the place to ask questions and house discussion about the *site*. When we get our own Third Place, then that will be an option for this kind of thing. For now, we can still leech off of chat.meta.stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't even know what a pokemon professor *is*...

Comment: I actually think Chat is a poor place to plan such a thing, as it lacks the nice threading.  But I agree its off topic.

Comment: @tzenes Maybe "perfect" is the wrong term. I don't know how organizing a succession game works, but having done lots of net-game scheduling for Suguri, Hisoutensoku, and various others on IRC, it doesn't sound too impractical. If threading is what you want... there's always Wave. ♪

Comment: @Grace Google Wave goes down at the end of the year.  A succession game is where you play a save for a set period of time (say 1 year in game) then you pass that save to the next person, who does the same.

Comment: @Oak Professor Oak is the leading intellectual authority on all matters Pokémon. It was a naming pun, is all. ♪

Comment: I love how we can joke around with the [link](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/859/i-love-how-we-can-joke-around-with-the-link/860#860)

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a [Dwarf Fortress room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198/dwarf-fortress-succession) in [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/) (currently only beta at meta.SO however).

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198/dwarf-fortress-succession