# Map Share Space

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, map-editor

With games like Starcraft 2 and Halo: Reach that allow users to create custom games and share them, can you explore the idea of setting up something where users can share their creations?

I was thinking a community wiki where people list their gaming id (i.e xbox live gamertag) and the map. Users can then comment on the map and such. I am torn if this belongs in the game development stack exchange or here.

One can argue that a custom map is similar to a gaming mod. We allow Q&A on mods ([example](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6725/is-goldeneye-source-free/6726#6726)). However creating mods is definitely not allowed here.

The gray area is what is Forge in Halo? If a user posts a question on how to use Forge, is that off topic? If a user asks where they can find custom maps created using Forge, is that off topic?

Personally, I think on gaming or on game-dev we need a place (chat room?) where users can share their maps / mods. I think this would build a stronger community relationship and also lead to strong question and answers.

Comment: I'll counter your edit with... "What is Forge in Halo?", as I don't actually know. But if any of it applies, [my previous stance on map editors](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/544/do-map-editor-questions-belong-here/564#564) is still the stance I hold today - I feel there is not enough difference between questions on how to use map-editor tools and how to use various other vanilla game-maker tools to justify allowing one but not the other. And the latter is definitely off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

Let us not for get that our website is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. As with [other forms of collaborative gaming or activity](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/859/dwarf-fortress-succession), this is not proper material for both the parent site and the meta site. It is primarily off-topic, as the site is not intended as a source of advertisement and testing user-generated content, but to get answers to questions. And a question of "What do you think of this map" is simply subjective and argumentative (maps are never going to be universally liked), leaving very little other reason to post these on the site.

I cannot judge how off-topic "map review" questions would be on the GameDev site. You would have to ask over there. I would assume off-topic, but that's just an assumption.

Independent of their being off-topic here and possibly there, we do have chat [as indicated by badp](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/map-share-space/1099#1099). So whether you're interested in getting opinions from gamers, or from game developers when they get their own chat, that will shape your decision on where to start these discussions. Certainly we have overlaps - some of us here are game designers while I imagine many of the devs are also going to be avid gamers - but it remains we are different communities so you'll get different opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Playing mods belongs to Gaming. That said, I think it's a better fit for our chat site. You could create an ad-hoc room and announce it here :)

Comment: But we apparently decided that map-editor questions [don't belong here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/544/do-map-editor-questions-belong-here). If we end up having a shared space, we'll have to make sure we keep it clear that we don't allow/support those questions here. I'm worried this will send mixed messages.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes, I have the same concerns. We allow questions on how to find mods but not how to create mods.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this is related to a Q&A site, whether it's a gaming Q&A site or a game-dev one. *Questions* about how to create content probably belong on game-dev, and *questions* about where to find content and how to play it probably belong here on gaming; but the actual content doesn't belong here.